# CASE WHEN EXIST return 0 when should return 1

Tags: sql, t-sql

In my `San_Imovel` table, I have a lot of property, and I would like to know if has some duplicates (Property in the same address). So, I get a address that I have sure that are many property in this same address, but in my `CASE WHEN EXIST` return 0.

Could someone help me ?

In the `SELECT` statement inside my `CASE WHEN EXITS` return 47 rows if I run it alone.

**QUERY**

```
declare @cityName as varchar(100)
declare @neighborName as varchar(100)
declare @zipcode as varchar(8)
declare @complement as varchar(100)
declare @street as varchar(100)
declare @number as varchar(6)
set @cityName = 'Sao Paulo'
set @neighborName = 'Tupi'
set @zipcode = '31840050'
set @complement = '123'
set @street = 'Furquim werneck'
set @number = '5989828'
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT City_Id, State_Id, CityName
    FROM City
    WHERE (CityName COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI) LIKE '' + @cityName + ''
)
select 
CASE
WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT San_Imovel.Imovel_Id 
        FROM San_Imovel
        WHERE San_Imovel.Number = @number 
        AND San_Imovel.ZipCode = @zipcode
        AND San_Imovel.Complement = @complement
        AND San_Imovel.Street = @street
        AND San_Imovel.City_Id = cte.City_Id
    ) 
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS ExistDuplicate
from cte
```

**DATA SAMPLE**

```
Imovel_Id bigint
Number int
Complement varchar
Street varchar
City_Id int
Zipcode varchar

Imovel_Id     Number    Complement   Street            City_Id   ZipCode
433669        5989828   123          Furquim Werneck   2754      31840050
433670        5989828   123          Furquim Werneck   2754      31840050
433671        5989828   123          Furquim Werneck   2754      31840050
```

Comment: What does the data in the tables look like?

Comment: Your query is correct, I bet your call isn't. Triple check the values you set the parameters to.

Comment: Should you use `N''`-strings and `nvarchar` on some places?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I'm not using `nvarchar` in my data types, so I think its not necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass your "number" parameter as integer if that's its data type in the db.

```
declare @number as int
set @number = 5989828
```